# missing \endgroup inserted in \lstlistings

Tags: listings

I am getting the following error

`missing \endgroup inserted`

```
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
 K$_{i}$ = $\displaystyle \frac{$\delta$}{max $\delta$} $
\end{lstlisting}
```

I just use the package `listings`

Comment: Why do you do a `$` within the arguments of `\frac`? Those are already in math mode.

Comment: why are you using listings here?  your `$` are clearly in the wrong place the second math escape is `$\displaystyle \frac{$` with just the start of the fraction.

Comment: @user3319015 What is the intended output?

Comment: I am new to using `\listings`.  After removing the `$` near `\delta`, I get the desired result.  @David Carlisle,@samcarter: I am using `\listing` to avoid equation numbers, and I am using it to show a snippet of pseudocode used in a different research paper. Thank You very much for your help

Comment: "using listings to avoid equation numbers"????????????????????? that is so weird. Every latex environment that adds an equation number has a version that does not add a number. here don't you just want `\[K_{i}= \frac{\delta}{\max \delta} \]` ???

Comment: @David  Yes, I exactly needed that. I am also new to LaTeX. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`listings` is for syntax highlighting computer program code, using it for mathematics is painful to enter and will produce weirdly typeset output.

You just seem to want an unnumbered math display so

```
\[K_{i}= \frac{\delta}{\max \delta} \]
```